# Android WebView and browser ignores second press of local (hash) link

Tags: android, user-interface, webview

I have some basic html loading in a webview, with a list at the top so that the user can jump to different sections and then click "back to top" on each section. What I've noticed is that if you click on one of the links it works correctly. If you then scroll back to that **same link** and click it again, nothing happens.

My guess is that the webview thinks that you are already at this page, so it is ignored, which would be fine for "real" links, but these are for navigation without leaving this page. Is there any way to "force" a refresh on a link that directs to the current page

Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
   <body id="pagetop"name="pagetop">

      <ul>
         <li>
            <p><a href="#one">One</a></p>
         </li>
         <li>
            <p><a href="#two">Two</a></p>
         </li>
         <li>
            <p><a href="#three">Three</a></p>
         </li>
      </ul>
      <div name="one" id="one">
            <p><a href="#pagetop">Back to top</a></p>
            <p>1 Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah 
            Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah 
            Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah 
            Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah 
            Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah 
            Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah 
            Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah </p>
      </div>
      <div name="two" id="two">
            <p><a href="#pagetop">Back to top</a></p>
            <p>2 Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah 
            Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah 
            Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah 
            Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah 
            Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah 
            Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah 
            Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah 
            Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah </p>
      </div>
      <div name="three" id="three">
            <p><a href="#pagetop">Back to top</a></p>
            <p>3 Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah 
            Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah 
            Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah 
            Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah 
            Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah 
            Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah 
            Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah  </p>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have the same problem with you,  did you use jQuery mobile?

Comment: No, this is straight Android. I might try to add some JS so that after a link click if the current url matches the clicked link then refresh, but this seems like more of a workaround than a fix.

Comment: After some testing it appears that it's not just webview, this behavior occurs on the Android browser on the Nexus One, on the Dolphin browser on the HTC Incredible, but NOT on the Samsung Galaxy Tab's built-in browser

Answer (score 0):

You might try adding a tag to the button somehow and overriding the WebViewClient.  I can type up a more specific answer if you give me a bit more info :)

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. I've tested with using both mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); and our our subclass of WebViewClient with shouldOverrideUrlLoading overloaded, but it seems that shouldOverrideUrlLoading is not called for hash links. 

This might be a bug in Android - http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2887